# For loop for a time step in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, tspan

I am trying to run a forloop through my tspan in my code, so that certain parameters change over time (Specifically, with each season).

This is what I have so far in that part of the code:

```
Tmax = 7300; %years times days
tspan = 0:1:Tmax; %tspan from day 1 to Tmax
Mu = [500 1500 500 0]; %vectors for each function of t, with values per season starting with spring
Day = zeros(Tmax,1);
count = 1;
for t = 1:Tmax
    S = floor(mod(t,365)/(366/4))+1; %Denotes the season
    Day(t) = Mu(S);
end
```

However, I keep getting the error "Undefined function or variable S." Any insights?

Comment: Are you sure this code reproduces your error?

Comment: Try putting a break point where you get the error, and look at the value of t (and S).

Answer (score -1):

It seem good and works for me. No errors. I would suggest to do:

```
clear all
```

And then try again. After running, if I plot Day, I get the following:
[image]

That was created with the following line:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It's now giving me the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." in line Day(t) = Mu(S). But when I call Mu(S) it returns the correct value, and Day(t) gives the same error. So I don't think it's running through the timestep in the way that I want it to, but am not sure how to fix the problem. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @SaraGagnon I repeated the code and it works fine for me as well. Check and see if your code in MATLAB is the exact code you published here. The variable `t` is an integer that goes up by step of 1 from 1 to 7300 so there is no reason for index error. And `S` is always an integer larger or equal to 1.

Comment: I agree with TJ1. Maybe you are running another piece of code that is messing it up.